# Google url scraping not looping lines in list box

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am trying to scrape results from google search, the tool need to browse pages one by one. However the issue is its not taking the all the list from the listbox. Its just working for the first line of the list box.

Startbtn Code

```
  foreach (string url in urlList.Items)
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + url);
                await PageLoad(30, 5);
                MessageBox.Show("sdsaD3");
                string pageSource = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
                Scrape(pageSource);
            }
```

--
Scrape Method

```
  private async void Scrape(string pageSource)
        {
                string regexExpression = "(?<=><div class=\"rc\"><div class=\"r\"><a href=\")(.*?)(?=\" onmousedown=)";
                Regex match = new Regex(regexExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline);
                MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(pageSource, regexExpression);
                for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
                {
                CommonCodes.WriteToTxt(collection[i].ToString(), "googlescrapedurls.txt");
                if (i == collection.Count - 1)
                {
                    var elementid = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext");
                    if (elementid != null)
                    {
                        for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++)
                        {
                            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
                            worker.RunWorkerAsync(w);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext") == null)
                    {
                          for(int pg=0; pg< urlList.Items.Count; pg++)
                    {
                      webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + urlList.Items[pg+1]);
                        CommonCodes.WaitXSeconds(10);
                        //await PageLoad(30, 5);
                        Scrape(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
                    }
                    }
                }


             }
```

--

```
Background worker code:
       BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => { gCaptcha(); }));
            webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => { webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext").InvokeMember("Click"); }));
            await PageLoad(30, 5);
            webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => { Scrape(webBrowser1.DocumentText); }));
```

---

pageload code

```
try
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> PageLoaded = null;
    PageLoaded = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    int TimeElapsed = 0;
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;
        if (PageLoaded.Task.IsCompleted) return; PageLoaded.SetResult(true);
    };
    //
    while (PageLoaded.Task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay * 1000);//interval of 10 ms worked good for me
        TimeElapsed++;
        if (TimeElapsed >= TimeOut * 100) PageLoaded.TrySetResult(true);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    CommonCodes.WriteLog(ex.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

--
The main problem is when I have 5 lines in listbox, for the first line only it is going to every page and scraping urls but for the other lines its not working properly. I don't understand the problem with in the code. Some how the code

```
MessageBox.Show("sdsaD3");
```

executing multiple time(If 5 lines in listbox then this msg boxpoping up 5 times). Thanks for the help.

EDit: I found the issue, it seems the issue is with await PageLoad(30, 5); but I am not sure how to invoke  async method. Any one have idea?

Comment: Have you debugged this, what did you find when you stepped through it?

Comment: Some how its going back to foreach loop.

Comment: This is against Googles terms and conditions. I would advise you don't do any of this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is encouraging illegal activity.

Comment: Hey nothing wrong in coding. If we use it then it is illegal. This is called trying new things. So stop saying illegal.

Comment: If youre gonna scrape Google data, add &adtest=on&num=100 . Then you query the test enviroment and you get 100 results on 1 request. No need to iterate pages.